# datepicker wont change value on change event of another input

Tags: javascript, laravel

what i want to do is, i am currently displaying today's date but on change event of an input field i want to set the min and max date of the datepicker. iif i remove the initial date the code works fine but if i keep the initial date it wont change the date after the event.
here is the js:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#datetime').datetimepicker({minDate: new Date()});
    });
$('#patient_id').change(function(){
        $('#datetime').val('');
        // var selVal = $(this).val();
        // sessionStorage.setItem("SelItem", selVal);
        var id = $('#patient_id').val();        
        var infoData = {id:id,'_token':token};
            $.when(chkexp(infoData)).then(function (dat) {
                const obj = JSON.parse(dat);
                var date = obj;
                var dateS = moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
                var today = new Date();
                var dateString = moment(today).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
                if(dateS < dateString){
                    $('#datetime').datetimepicker({minDate: dateS, maxDate: dateS});
                }else{
                    $('#datetime').datetimepicker({minDate: new Date(), maxDate: dateS });
                }

            });
        });  
    function chkexp(infoData) {
        var url = baseurl+'/appointments/checkexpiry';
        return $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: infoData,
            type: 'post',
        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think there is a data value and date format issue which are getting passed to date picker dynamically. Try with explicit date format as per your needs like below one for d.m.y format,

```
{minDate:'05.12.2013',formatDate:'d.m.Y'}
```

Comment: if(dateS < dateString){
                    $('#datetime').datetimepicker({minDate: dateS, maxDate: dateS, format: "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm A"});
                }else{
                    $('#datetime').datetimepicker({minDate: new Date(), maxDate: dateS, format: "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm A"});
                } already tried

Comment: the only problem is every time i select a patient i want the set dates to change but the date gets changed only once. eg. if i select a patient then i get a date but if i select another patient i get the same date. i want that to change. works fine when page is refreshed. can it be done without refreshing the page??